# In the java protocol buffers 3 api, how can the descriptor object be used to check if a oneof is set?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a generic proto 2 bson document converter and using the descriptors to map the values. I'm having a time finding the correct method within the java protobuf api to tell me if a oneof is set.

What I have so far is:

```
      } else if (descriptor.getContainingOneof() != null) {
    final OneofDescriptor containingOneof = descriptor.getContainingOneof();
    for (FieldDescriptor oneOfField : containingOneof.getFields()){
      //how to check if the oneof is set and how to find which field in the oneof has the value?
    }
```

I am toying with this but isInitialized returns true even if the oneof isn't set.

```
   if (message.hasField(descriptor)) {
      final boolean initialized = containingOneof.getOptions().isInitialized();
      for (var oneOfItem : containingOneof.getFields()) {
        var field = message.getField(oneOfItem);
        if(field != null) {
          //the field
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Note that your question would be clearer if you showed us the proto and explained what `descriptor` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want `message.getOneofFieldDescriptor(containingOneof)`. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder.html#getOneofFieldDescriptor-com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.OneofDescriptor-):

> Obtains the FieldDescriptor if the given oneof is set. Returns null if no field is set.

Note that your `isInitialized()` call is just checking whether the [`OneofOptions`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DescriptorProtos.OneofOptions.html) message associated with the oneof is initialized - it has nothing to do with `message`.